# Getting nullpointerexception error for Appium error while running TestNg

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, testng, appium

```
public class screen_detects_ extends Base {


 @Test
 public void testing() {

  try {

   page tutorial = new page(driver);
   tutorial.skipTutorial(driver);

   boardpage v = new boardpage(driver);
   v.clickOnDashBoardButton(driver);

   v.tapOnSignInAP("jkjk@gmail.com", "tatata");
   v.clickOnMyTickets();

   vicketsAndasses backbutton = new vicketsAndasses(driver);
   backbutton.clickBackButton();
  } catch (Exception exp) {
   exp.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}
```

base.java
//This class extends from main one. I get an error from driver or //configuration.

```
public class base {
 public static final Logger LOGGER = Log.getDefaultLogger();
 protected AppiumDriver driver;
 protected String platform;
 protected String environment;
 protected JSONObject jsonConfig;

 // @beforemethod(alwaysRun = true)
 // @parameters({ "appName", "platform", "platformVersion", "deviceName","seleniumUrl", "environment", "enableEnv", "ticketFutureDate" })

 public void setUp(@optional String appName, @optional String platform, @optional String platformVersion, @optional String deviceName, @optional String seleniumUrl, @optional String environment, @optional String enableEnv, @optional String ticketFutureDate, ITestContext ctx, Method method) throws Exception {

  if (appName == null || appName.isEmpty() || environment == null || enableEnv == null) {
   JSONObject jsonCapabilities = DataProviderHelper.readCapabilities();
   appName = jsonCapabilities.getString("appName");
   platform = jsonCapabilities.getString("platform");
   platformVersion = jsonCapabilities.getString("platformVersion");
   deviceName = jsonCapabilities.getString("deviceName");
   seleniumUrl = jsonCapabilities.getString("seleniumUrl");
   environment = jsonCapabilities.isNull("environment") ? null :
    jsonCapabilities.getString("environment");
   enableEnv = jsonCapabilities.getString("enableEnv");
   ticketFutureDate = jsonCapabilities.getString("ticketFutureDate");
  }

  this.platform = platform;
  this.environment = environment;

  System.out.println("********************************************");
  System.out.println("appName= " + appName);
  System.out.println("platform= " + platform);
  System.out.println("platformVersion= " + platformVersion);
  System.out.println("deviceName= " + deviceName);
  System.out.println("seleniumUrl= " + seleniumUrl);
  System.out.println("environment= " + environment);
  System.out.println("enableEnv= " + enableEnv);
  System.out.println("ticketFutureDate= " + ticketFutureDate);
  System.out.println("********************************************");

  this.driver = BaseTest.setupDriver(appName, platform, platformVersion, deviceName, seleniumUrl, environment, enableEnv, ticketFutureDate, ctx, method);


  //Parse FP object from json
  //TestDataHelper.loadTestData(TestDataHelper.ANDROID_JSON_FILE);
 }

 // @aftermethod(alwaysRun = true)
 public void tearDown() {
  BaseTest.quitDriver(driver);
 }

 public JSONObject getGeneralJson() throws JSONException {
  String fileName = TestDataHelper.ANDROID_JSON_FILE;
  //fileName = fileName.split("\.")[fileName.split("\.").length - 1];
  String jsonpath = TestDataHelper.ANDROID_JSON_FILE_LOCATION;
  jsonpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + Constants.DIR_SEPARATOR +
   jsonpath;
  jsonpath = jsonpath + fileName;

  String jsonString = null;
  try {
   jsonString = DataProviderHelper.readFileAsString(jsonpath);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return new JSONObject(jsonString);
 }
}
```

Console TestNg Results;

```
08-30 22:23:02.712 [com.disney.appium.scripts.iOS.aprenewals.T1632401_Verify_ap_screen_detects_ap_renewal_eligibility AP_Renewals] Skip Tutorial
**java.lang.NullPointerException**--
```

> ('//error I don't know how to fix it. I'm not sure if its with a
>   driver or client or configurations')
>
> ('io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.
>         (AppiumElementLocator.java:72)')
>         at

```
io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:26)
        at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:65)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:107)
        at com.disney.apps.dlr.pageObjects.iOS.Tutorial.Tutorial_iOSPage.<init>(Tutorial_iOSPage.java:50)
        at com.disney.appium.scripts.iOS.aprenewals.T1632401_Verify_ap_screen_detects_ap_renewal_eligibility.AP_Renewals(T1632401_Verify_ap_screen_detects_ap_renewal_eligibility.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
    PASSED: AP_Renewals

    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

page class

```
public class Page
{

  private AppiumDriver  driver;

  final private String TUTORIAL_CLOSE = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='Close']";

  @iOSFindBy( id = "tutorialPageImage1" )
  private MobileElement tutorial_image1;

  @iOSFindBy( id = "tutorialPageImage2" )
  private MobileElement tutorial_image2;

  @iOSFindBy( id = "tutorialPageImage3" )
  private MobileElement tutorial_image3;


  @iOSFindBy( xpath =  TUTORIAL_CLOSE)
  private MobileElement tutorial_close;

  @iOSFindBy (accessibility = "Get Started")
  private MobileElement get_started;  

  public Page( final AppiumDriver driver ) 
  {
    this.driver = driver;    
    PageFactory.initElements( new AppiumFieldDecorator( driver , AppiumConstants.IMPLICITLY_WAIT_TIMEOUT , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) , this );
  }



  public boolean verifyTutorialScreen()
  {
    AutomationTools.waitForElementToLoad( driver , tutorial_image1, 10 );
    Assert.assertEquals( true , tutorial_image1.isDisplayed() , "Tutorial screen not found" );
    Log.log(driver).info( "Verified Tutorial screen" );
    return true;
  }

  public boolean clickOnDismissScreen()
  {
    AutomationTools.waitForElementToLoad( driver , tutorial_close, 10 );
    tutorial_close.click();
    Log.log(driver).info( "Clicked on Dismiss Tutorial" );
    return true;
  }


  public void skipTutorial(AppiumDriver driver) throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      // Verify Tutorial screen displayed      
      if(verifyTutorialScreenDisplayed()) //pagesource.contains("Close"))
      {      
        // Dismiss the Tutorial screen displayed
        iosHelper.clickElementBtn(driver, By.xpath(TUTORIAL_CLOSE), tutorial_close);
        //iosHelper.closeScreen(driver);
        Log.log(driver).info("Tutorial screen displayed and closed" );
      }
      else
        Log.log(driver).info("Tutorial screen not displayed");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      Assert.fail("Unable to dismiss the Tutorial screen: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }



  public boolean verifyTutorialScreenDisplayed() throws Exception
  {
    boolean isTutorialDisplayed = false;    
    try
    {
      isTutorialDisplayed = iosHelper.verifyElementDisplayed(driver, tutorial_image1); 
      Log.log(driver).info( "Verified Tutorial screen" ); 
      return isTutorialDisplayed;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      Assert.fail("Tutorial screen Image not displayed: " + e.getMessage());
      return false;
    }   
  }

  public void verifyTutorialPages() throws Exception
  {  
    try
    {
      Assert.assertTrue(iosHelper.verifyElementDisplayed(driver, tutorial_image1),""); 
      Log.log(driver).info( "Verified Tutorial screen Page 1" ); 

      iosHelper.swipeElementToUpDirection(driver, tutorial_image2);

      Assert.assertTrue(iosHelper.verifyElementDisplayed(driver, tutorial_image2),""); 
      Log.log(driver).info( "Verified Tutorial screen Page 2" ); 

      iosHelper.swipeElementToUpDirection(driver, tutorial_image3);

      Assert.assertTrue(iosHelper.verifyElementDisplayed(driver, tutorial_image3),""); 
      Log.log(driver).info( "Verified Tutorial screen Page 3" ); 

      // Tap on Get Started button
      Log.log(driver).info("Tap on Get Started button after tutorial pages verified");
      get_started.click();     
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      Assert.fail("Tutorial pages has not verified completely: " + e.getMessage());     
    }   
  }
```

}

Comment: What does your `page` class look like ? The exception is arising from your `page` class.

Comment: What you think?

Comment: We still seem to be missing some parts. Your stacktrace suggests that your NPE is originating from `com.disney.appium.scripts.iOS.aprenewals.T1632401_Verify_ap_screen_detects_ap_renewal_eligibility.AP_Renewals` but I don't see any such class in your code snippet. Can you please help clean up your post and include the proper stacktrace ? I am also not seeing any explicit invocation of `base.setup() ` and the annotations in it are commented out as well. Its hard to figure out.

Comment: I get this error: Do you know why? [com.disney.appium.common.BaseTestUtilities buildDriver] appPath: /Users//Downloads/DLR.app
09-04 12:04:21.671 [com..appium.common.BaseTestUtilities getSeleniumUrl] Selenium URL: http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
09-04 12:05:09.538 [com..appium.common.Test setupDriver] before break, never made it to catch statement